# Holding activity instance in fragment: can it result in a memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have an `Activity` with some `Fragment`s. From each fragment, I need to call `aMethod()` implemented by the Activity. So, I do something like this:

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).aMethod();
```

I'm referencing the activity many times, so I decided hold a reference to the activity. When fragment is created, I have:

```
MyActivity act; // this s a fragment's member
//...
act = (MyActivity) getActivity();
```

I'm wondering if holding that reference could result in a memory leak.

If so, I have thought in two solutions:

1. `act = null;` when fragment is destroyed (`onDestroy()`)
2. Using a `WeakReference`: `act = new WeakReference((MyActivity) getActivity());`

Are both valid? Does it make sense?

Comment: I believe it won't result in memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope that's not memory leak.

We are getting instance of Activity from where we can load fragment.

so you also need to pass instance of Activity or As per you already do casting and through getActivity() is correct.

But Remember one thing whenever onPause(), onStop() and onDestroy() called at that time to release instace of Activity otherwise it holds memory and Garbage collector not clear it so in such senario/situations only memory leak occurs.

Comment: So if I don't release the reference to the activity in that methods, it could result in memory leak, right?

Comment: you can also see in android monitor view and also using heap of apk to see it.

Comment: you can do using above way to release instance of activity and reused when it onResume() to getInstance again using if(getActivity!=null){
// your casting code here. }

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need to hold a reference. Just keep using

```
getActivity()
```

A fragment lifecycle is joined to that of its activity so you don't need to worry about it.

If you still want to store a reference, a safe bet is to use the WeakReference as you said yourself.

This will make the reference available for garbage collection when needed. Just keep checks for not null before using the reference though.